# Алгоритм синхронизации таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется таблица пользователей, в которую ежедневно должна заноситься история изменения их состояния:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
    `user_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
    , `day` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL
    , `action` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
    , PRIMARY KEY(`user_id`,`day`)
    , INDEX(`day`)
)
```

Колонка `day` - номер дня, колонка `action` - событие о том, добавлен ли пользователь (значение, например, "1") или был удалён (значение "0").

Проблема заключается в том, что пользователей очень много (от 1 миллиона) и требуется выполнять синхронизацию с поступившими данными максимально возможно быстро и экономно в отношении расхода памяти.

Поступающие данные (из сети) по пользователям можно аккумулировать в отдельной таблице, а затем уже производить синхронизацию. Собственно, я так и поступил, однако в связи с тем, что это - таблица истории, а не, скажем, просто текущего состояния, запросы на синхронизацию становятся очень ресурсоёмкими. Например приходится учитывать, что каждый из пользователей может быть удалён (значение в `action` - "0"), а спустя день вновь добавлен (значение "1"). И такие "качели" (добавлен-удалён-добавлен) могут происходить изо дня в день.

Возможно имеет смысл перед синхронизацией создать отдельную таблицу, куда скинуть всех пользователей с их текущим состоянием, т.е. создать этакий снимок их состояний на текущий момент. Произвести синхронизацию поступивших данных с этой временной таблицей и лишь затем только изменивших своё состояние пользователей перезаписать в целевой таблице. Но у меня, к сожалению, нет уверенности, что данный подход будет быстрее работать, поскольку так или иначе всё равно потребуется прочитать целевую таблицу полностью с тем, чтобы сделать копию последних на момент синхронизации состояний.

Возможно имеется решение интереснее, нежели чем то, что мне удалось придумать. Прошу подсказать.

**Update**

Поступающие на синхронизацию данные - это список идентификаторов пользователей, которые имеются на текущий момент времени.

**Update 2**

Список пользователей приходит изо дня в день почти один и тот же, но с изменениями для некоторого кол-ва пользователей. Части из них, что были ранее, не будет, но появляются и новые. Вот эту разницу в составе и нужно определять, дописывая в таблицу истории строки с изменениями по каждому пользователю, если таковые были. Если же пришедшие данные такие же, что есть в целевой таблице (списки пользователей равны), то целевая таблица вообще не меняется.

Comment: Как то странно смотрится "номер дня" почему например не два поля "интервал дат" что бы не городить подряд кучу одинаковых записей 1 1 1. А поступающие извне данные в каком виде, типа списка id пользователей которые сегодня есть ?

Comment: @Mike , вместо номера дня можно просто таймстамп или что-то ещё, суть роли не меняет. Просто получается, что для каждого пользователя нужно вести дату, когда с ним что-то произошло (добавлен или удалён). Если изменений не было, то есть, например, он был ранее добавлен, а на следующий день в пришедших данных он всё также значится, то ничего не меняем и не добавляем. А поступающие данные, Вы правы, это именно список идентификаторов пользователей, что есть на текущий момент.

Comment: @Mike , я опечатался, когда писал вопрос. В `PRIMARY KEY` две колонки: и `user_id`, и `day`. То есть важно сохранить все изменения состояний и когда они произошли.

Comment: Я говорил именно про интервал. Почему у вас именно "день" если пользователь вчера появился и есть сегодня, в вашей таблице будет одна запись  "вчера" что он добавлен, на сегодняшний день записи не будет вообще ? или будет "вчера" и "сегодя" и в обоих 1

Comment: @Mike , если пользователь был вчера и сегодня, то запись будет только за вчера. То есть в таблицу новые строки заносим только при изменении состояния.

Comment: И тогда выходит, что сейчас запрос текущего состояния выглядит как "получить запись с максимальной датой для данного user_id", если грамотно, с order by и limit то в принципе должно быть приемлемо по времени... А вообще вердикт: Я бы вообще не делал этого в базе. Держал бы последнее загруженное состояние в быстрозагружаемом в скрипт формате. сейчас попробовал на perl загрузить с диска 2 хеша по 1 млн записей и сравнить. уходит 3 секунды. дальше записать в БД только найденную разницу

Comment: @Mike , видите, тут каждый раз нужно производить сравнение в обе стороны - двунаправленная, полная синхронизация. Если вновь пришедший список пользователей не имеет некоторых из тех, что присутствуют в таблице истории, то этот факт в этой самой истории должен быть отмечен. Фактически нужно проверить каждого пользователя на предмет наличия / неналичия в обоих списках. К сожалению, получается очень тяжко, тем более, что таких таблиц историй несколько сотен, хранить этот объём информации, кроме как в БД больше негде.

Comment: Ну так в базе продолжать хранить историю. А скрипт загрузчик после того как запишет в базу очередную порцию данных последнее состояние пишет в своем формате на диск. Без упаковки 1 млн записей от 1 до 1 млн занимает 8 Мб. При следующей загрузке он поднимает с диска последнее состояние и сверяет с ним, не вычитывая заново БД

Comment: @Mike , понял Вас. То есть идея хранения последнего состояния получается самой правильной в данной ситуации.

Comment: Думаю да, с ней гораздо проще сверять. Если в sql через full outer join переклеил две таблицы - вот и вся разница. Дальнейшая оптимизация - вынесение из базы текущих состояний для сверки в ОЗУ

Comment: Оформите как ответ, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сверять проще списки ID без дополнительной информации. Нам надо хранить в отдельной таблице список ID пользователей, которые в данный момент считаются существующими (ваш статус 1 в таблице истории). Хранить id не существующих в последней редакции вообще не нужно. Загружаем в временную таблицу новый входящий список и сверяем запросом вроде:

```
insert into hystory(id, dt, state)
select id, now(), 1
  from NEW left join OLD on NEW.id=OLD.id
 where OLD.id is null
union
select id, now(), 0
  from NEW right join OLD on NEW.id=OLD.id
 where NEW.id is null
```

После чего нам надо еще удалить/добавить записи в таблицу последнего состояния. Если БД не MySQL и поддерживает операции `FULL OUTER JOIN` или `MINUS` это упростит запрос в 2 раза.

Вариант 2: Если у нас в БД много подряд идущих или близко расположенных ID то можно пробовать хранить текущее состояние в виде записей содержащих начальный ID диапазона из 64 значений и битовую маску в виде bitint в которой существующие на данный момент ID отмечены единичными битами. Сравнивающий запрос строит входящие ID в таком же формате, переклеивает таблицы и битовыми операциями находит разницу.

Вариант 3: Производить сравнение списков старых и новых ID не в БД, а в внешнем скрипте. Список из 1 млн значений легко сравнивается в оперативной памяти за пару секунд. После чего в БД в таблицу истории пишутся изменения. А скрипт сохраняет новый текущий список существующих id в файл на диск в формате, удобном скрипту для быстрого чтения в будущем.

Comment: Развёрнутый ответ с вариантами, спасибо большое.